# JavaScript or JQuery code to randomly place a jpg image in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a website for a client and have a table on the very top containing a 728x90 jpg image. The client will be receiving numerous 728x90 images from sponsors and wants these images to randomly be placed in when you refresh your browser.

I've seen this used on tech news sites like the top of [macrumors.com](http://www.macrumors.com). That's exactly what I want to do. I'd like to use some sort of JavaScript or JQuery code that allows me to define the image names to randomly use or image folder containing images the client could easily place pictures that it will randomly choose from; the last is preferred.

Thank you for any help!

Jeff

Comment: Do you know any JavaScript or do you want someone to write the whole thing for you?

Comment: So where is the code from this website you're talking about..

Comment: Please provide code when you are asking a question, even if it is just the html and what you have attempted thus far. Please also attempt to google for a solution before coming straight here. A search for 'Display Random Image Javascript' returned a plethora of useful results.

Answer (score 0):

I've not done this before, but here are a couple of things you could try:

1. Have a simple web backend that, when hit, reads the image directory for all files and randomly chooses one to give back to you.
2. Use [requestFileSystem](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/) to implement the above in javascript
3. Keep your image names in javascript code and random choose from them.

Then, once you have an image selected, you could:

1. Change the src attribute of the image element
2. Create an [Image](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_image.asp) element and attach it to the DOM

Options 1 and 1 are probably easiest, but figured I'd shoot out a couple more ideas.